# adding a mailbox in powershell, permission denied

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I am trying to add one single mailbox on exchange 2013 via powershell and getting and 'access denied' error.

```
PS C:\Software> Enable-Mailbox -Identity AreallyTest
Enable-Mailbox : Unable to generate the e-mail address. Unable to load address module 'X:\Exchange\Mailbox\address\SMTP\AMD64\inproxy.dll' for address type
'SMTP'. Additional message: 'Access is denied'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Enable-Mailbox -Identity AreallyTest
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Enable-Mailbox], RusException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : [Server=EXCH01,RequestId=cfea9121-4f0a-41f4-84e9 -2489f3228410,TimeStamp=10/13/2014 8:06:33 AM] [FailureCategory=Cmdlet-Rus Exception] 593F2A65,Microsoft.Exchange.Management.RecipientTasks.EnableMaiLbox
```

The user does exist.
How I get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows domain naming is where you are in error.

Add the NetBios domain as a prefix like this:

```
Enable-Mailbox -Identity domain\AreallyTest
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to run the command in an elevated console (run as admin)

Comment: This is not true, since Exchange connection relies on remoting no elevation is needed (I've never had to elevate to do things on an Exchange server using Powershell in the past 10 years)